# How do I count number of tabs in screenshot using OpenCV houghlines?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, edge-detection, hough-transform

I am trying to count number of tabs in screenshot using OpenCV. I first cropped my image to limit to chrome tabs. Then I used edge detection, Canny algorithm to find edges in chrome. Then I am using Houghlines to find number of tabs, but I am not getting the required ouput through Houghlines.  Below is my code and output.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import math
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
img = cv2.imread('1.png')

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
edges = cv2.Canny(gray,50,200,apertureSize = 3)
cv2.imwrite('result.png',edges)
lines = cv2.HoughLines(edges,1,np.pi/180,50)

for rho,theta in lines[0]:
  slope = 180*theta*1.0/np.pi
  if slope > 110 and slope <148: # for identifying chrome tab angle (right slope line of each tab)
    a = np.cos(theta)
    b = np.sin(theta)
    x0 = a*rho
    y0 = b*rho
    x1 = int(x0 + 1000*(-b))
    y1 = int(y0 + 1000*(a))
    x2 = int(x0 - 1000*(-b))
    y2 = int(y0 - 1000*(a))
    cv2.line(img,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(0,0,255),3)
cv2.imwrite('result2.png',img)
```

[image: Original cropped image]
[image: Final Image]

[image: Firefox image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Very interesting:D 
A really simple solution would be to binarize your image and to define a line in the upper area of the image and get the gray values. Then you could count the intersections. Here is an example:
[image: Finding number of tabs from gray value profile]

The fancy algorithms arent always the best solution. Define what you want to do and try to find a solution as simple as possible.

Here is my solution in C++. Quick and dirty ;)

```
#include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include <vector>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

Mat src, binary, morph, gray, morph_rgb;

/**
*Compute number of tabs 
*/
int getNumberOfTabs(Mat& src, int start_col, int stop_col, int search_row, bool draw=false);

/**
* @function main
*/
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    const int morph_size = 2;
    const int start_col = 5;
    const int stop_col = 1750;
    const int row_index = 2;
    /// Load an image
    src = imread("C:\\Users\\phili\\Pictures\\Tab.png", 1);

    //Convert for binarization
    cvtColor(src, gray, CV_RGB2GRAY);
    threshold(gray, binary, 164, 255, 1);

    //Remove icons and text on tabs
    Mat element = getStructuringElement(CV_SHAPE_RECT, Size(2 * morph_size + 1, 2 * morph_size + 1), Point(morph_size, morph_size));
    morphologyEx(binary, morph, CV_MOP_OPEN, element);

    int nmb_tabs = getNumberOfTabs(morph, start_col, stop_col, row_index, true);

    imshow("Original", src);
    imshow("Binary", binary);
    imshow("Binary", morph);


    /// Wait until user finishes program
    while (true)
    {
        int c;
        c = waitKey(20);
        if ((char)c == 27)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

}

int getNumberOfTabs(Mat& src,int start_col,int stop_col, int row_index, bool draw)
{
    int length = stop_col - start_col;

    //Extract gray value profil
    Mat profil = cv::Mat(0, length, CV_8U);
    profil = src.colRange(start_col, stop_col).row(row_index);

    Mat src_rgb;
    if (draw)
    {       
        cvtColor(src, src_rgb, CV_GRAY2RGB);
        line(src_rgb, Point(start_col, row_index), Point(stop_col, row_index), Scalar(0, 0, 255), 2);
    }

    //Convolve profil with [1 -1] to detect edges
    unsigned char* input = (unsigned char*)(profil.data);
    vector<int> positions;
    for (int i = 0; i < stop_col - start_col - 1; i++)
    {
        //Kernel
        int first = input[i];
        int second = input[i + 1];
        int ans = first - second;

        //Positiv or negativ slope ?
        if (ans < 0)
        {
            positions.push_back(i + 1);
            if(draw)
                circle(src_rgb, Point(i + start_col, row_index), 2, Scalar(255,0, 0), -1);
        }
        else if (ans > 0)
        {
            positions.push_back(i);
            if (draw)
                circle(src_rgb, Point(i + start_col + 1, row_index), 2, Scalar(255,0, 0), -1);
        }

    }
    if (draw)
        imshow("Detected Edges", src_rgb);
    //Number of tabs
    return positions.size() / 2;
}
```

and the results with the search line in red and the detected edges in blue:
[image]

Comment: Hey. I am new to this topic. Can you tell me what did you do to binarize the image? I have sets of images. I wanted to find the mean of number of  tabs of all images

Comment: I used [ImageJ](https://imagej.nih.gov/ij/). It is an open -source image-processing tool. You can test some ideas without the need to create a new projects,...! [Here](https://imagingbook.com/source/) you can download some useful plugins. But basicly i converted the image to 8bit with, used a global threshold (see the 8bit image histogram) and did a binarization. In OpenCV you could load the image with the flag `CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE` or convert the color image with `cv2.cvtColor` and do the thresholding with `cv2.threshold`.

Comment: Thank you. I am able to binarize the image. Could you please help me how do I count the intersection with the help of a line? I am using opencv with python

Comment: Hey, although the solution works for this image, it cannot be used for all sets of images. Considering we have images of different browsers, or even browsers running on different OS. I believe start_col should be dynamic. What do you think?

Comment: I assumed there all chrome tabs, please add these Information to the question! You should try how well the other images are binarized and if the threshold works for all of them. For automation you need to find a feature that is similar in all the tabs( like exit button, tab add button,...  I dont know) and set your search line accordingly! Can you provide some more samples?

Comment: Updated the question. Added a ubuntu chrome image, and the fourth image is the one where binarization was not proper. I took average of top right 4 pixels values and then used THRESH_BINARY_INV.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121697/discussion-between-pschn-and-piyush-agarwal).